# Firebase Authentication fails after publishing App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using 2 google accounts and 2 different firebase projects for Development and Release for android app.
I have Implemented Google Authentication on both of them.
Both operate well when I have the build. i.e Dev also performs Authentication and release build as well.
When I publish my app on Google Play Console and download it via play store, Google Authentication fails. It gives Error "**Sign In Cancelled! RC: 0**"

Comment: Hey @saransh, did my answer help you solve your issue?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit We had already managed this thing. Though we can see A difference in some parameters of the JSON file we are using and what it is currently for each project, as we had changed the Keys once in the middle of development. Thanks for taking our mindset in that direction. We will replace the files and post back here if that works or not. It Might take 6-7 hours to stabilize things, and get it ready on Play Store.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit None of the things worked.

Comment: That's weird, are you sure, everything works perfectly in debug app? Also, can you take a look at the new SHA1, which should be different from the previous one,  is properly added or not?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit The following Trick Worked: We were signing the application with credentials that generated separate keys for both debug and release version. We added those keys on firebase console. When we looked at Google Play Console we found totally different SHA1 key. We used that key now everywhere in our firebase project and all. Things worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got solution.....

Open **Play console** -> **Release Management** -> **App Sign in** -> **SHA-1 Certificate**.

Copy SHA-1 Key and Past in Firebase Console

Go To **Firebase Project** -> **Project Setting** -> **SHA Certificate Fingerprint** -> **Add Fingerprint**-> Paste **SHA-1 Key**

Answer (score 3):

The SHA-1 certificate is now under App Integrity

Answer (score 1):

For Users of the NEW PLAY CONSOLE ( by the time I am writting this is in Beta).

Open **Play console** -> **Choose your App (Click)** -> **(Release section) Click Setup** -> **App Sign in** -> **(App signing key certificate) SHA-1 Certificate**.

Copy SHA-1 and SHA-256 Key and Paste in Firebase Console in your App Settings.

If you are using Facebook Login as well you may need to convert your SHA-1 to Key Hash.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that release APK and debug APK has different `SHA1` and different API keys for google services.

Both of them must be added in Firebase.

Steps:

**Firebase Console -> Project settings.**

Download `google-services.json` from here, add it to project and recompile with release keystore using option "Build signed APK". That should work, and now your authentication should not be failing.

To get the new New SHA1, just go to 
**Released Management->App Sigining** on your play console.

Comment: I have added all both SHA 1 and SHA 256 but the problem is that the `google-services.json` that I download from Firebase Console doesn't contain all these certificates. It contains only debug SHA 1. Any idea how to fix that?